# Using cat and grep to print line and its number but ignore at the same time blank lines

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep, cat

I have created a simple script that prints the contents of a text file using cat command. Now I want to print a line along with its number, but at the same time I need to ignore blank lines. The following format is desired:

```
1 George Jones Berlin 2564536877
2 Mike Dixon Paris 2794321976
```

I tried using

```
cat -n catalog.txt | grep -v '^$' catalog.txt
```

But I get the following results:

```
 George Jones Berlin 2564536877
 Mike Dixon Paris 2794321976
```

I have managed to get rid of the blank lines, but line's number is not printed. What am I doing wrong?

Here are the contents of catalog.txt:

```
 George Jones Berlin 2564536877

 Mike Dixon Paris 2794321976
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution doesn't work because `cat -n catalog.txt` is already giving you non-blank lines.

You can pipe `grep`'s output to `cat -n`:

```
grep -v '^$' yourFile | cat -n
```

Example:

**test.txt**:

```
Hello

how
are


you
?
```

---

```
$ grep -v '^$' test | cat -n
     1  Hello
     2  how
     3  are
     4  you
     5  ?
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. BTW why doesn't it work the other way around (using cat first and grep second)?

Comment: @JohnM. Because `cat -n` is already giving you output without blank lines, so `grep` won't find the match. Try to output only `cat -n catalog.txt` and see what's the output, then check what your regex matches in `grep`.

Answer (score 2):

At first glance, you should drop the file name in the command line to `grep` to make `grep` read from stdin:

```
cat -n catalog.txt | grep -v '^$'
                                  ^^^
```

In your code, you supplied `catalog.txt` to `grep`, which made it read from the file and ignore its standard input. So you're basically `grepping` from the file instead of the output of `cat` piped to its stdin.

To correctly ignore blank lines the prepend line numbers, switch the order of `grep` and `cat`:

```
grep -v '^$' catalog.txt | cat -n
```

Answer (score 2):

single, simple, basic `awk` solution could help you here.

***Solution 1st:***

```
awk 'NF{print FNR,$0}' Input_file
```

***Solution 2nd:*** Above will print line number including the line number of NULL lines, in case you want to leave empty lines line number then following may help you in same.

```
awk '!NF{FNR--;next} NF{print FNR,$0}'  Input_file
```

***Solution 3rd:*** Using only `grep`, though output will have a colon in between line number and the line.

```
grep -v '^$' Input_file | grep -n '.*'
```

***Explanation of Solution 1st:***
`NF`: Checking condition here if `NF`(Number of fields in current line, it is `awk`'s out of the box variable which has the value of number of fields in a line) is NOT NULL, if this condition is TRUE then following the actions mentioned next to it.
`{print FNR,$0}`: Using `print` function of `awk` here to print `FNR`(Line number, which will have the line's number in it, it is `awk`'s out of box variable) then print `$0` which means current line.

By this we satisfy OP's both the conditions of leaving empty lines and print the line numbers along with lines too. I hope this helps you.

Comment: Can confirm,this works nicely as well, though it's a bit more complicated. Anyway, it's very useful to know how to use awk.

Comment: @JohnM., TRUST me it is not at all complicated :). I added my explanation too let me know if you feel any confusions too.

Comment: Appreciate the explanation. I understand why this isn't complicated, but i forgot to mention that i'm new to linux, so most things aren't really simple to do. Compared to windows, this is a new world.

Comment: @JohnM.. also added 1 more solution where it will leave the line numbers of NULL lines, it will not consider them in output's line number thing.

Answer (score 2):

Another `awk`

```
$ awk 'NF{$0=FNR  " " $0}NF' 48488182
1 George Jones Berlin 2564536877
3 Mike Dixon Paris 2794321976
```

The second line was blank in this case.